# MongoDB: Update multidimensional array using their object IDs

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

I am developing a resume database Web Application using Node.js and MongoDB. I am trying to update a single record located inside a multidimensional array. How do I update a single array from the **career_development** field bellow given that each array have their own object ID?

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57f35a25983d521a90518efd"),
    "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-10-04T07:28:37.407Z"),
    "career_development": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 1",
            "company_location": "Texas, United States"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811afb7b7880316e4497407"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 2",
            "company_location": "South Carolina, United States"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811afbfb7880316e4497408"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 3",
            "company_location": "Florida, United States"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use the [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) with the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document/#document-dot-notation) as `db.collection.update({ "career_development._id": ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406") }, { "$set": { "career_development.$.company_name": "TestCompanyName 1 Updated" } })`

Comment: @chridam thanks, that works. but what if say career_development is dynamic? how can I do it something like: 

var dynamic_variable = posted_data.type;

{ "$set": { dynamic_variable + ".$.company_name": "TestCompanyName 1 Updated" } } ??

Comment: No problem. You can create an update object using the bracket notation as 
`var dynamic_variable = posted_data.type; 
var query = {};
var updateObj = { "$set": { } };  
query[dynamic_variable +"._id"] = ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406");
updateObj["$set"][dynamic_variable +".$.company_name"] = "TestCompanyName 1 Updated"; 
db.collection.update(query, updateObj)`

Comment: @chridam Thanks for the help, it is working perfectly now. Could you please put both your 2 comments in 1 answer so I could mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) with the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document/#document-dot-notation) as

```
db.collection.update(
    { "career_development._id": ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406") }, 
    { 
        "$set": { 
            "career_development.$.company_name": "TestCompanyName 1 Updated" 
        } 
    }
);
```

If `career_development` is dynamic, then you can create an update object using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) as:

```
var dynamic_variable = posted_data.type,
    query = {},
    updateObj = { "$set": { } }; 

query[dynamic_variable +"._id"] = ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406"); 
updateObj["$set"][dynamic_variable +".$.company_name"] = "TestCompanyName 1 Updated"; 
db.collection.update(query, updateObj)
```

Comment: Thank you for this @chridam

Comment: @Carlo No worries, always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the array looks like this? If that is not the case we can user elemMatch to get the doc, loop over it and update it. Let me know, I will post the query over here.

```
"career_development": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 1",
            "company_location": "Texas, United States"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811afb7b7880316e4497407"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 2",
            "company_location": "South Carolina, United States"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811afbfb7880316e4497408"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 3",
            "company_location": "Florida, United States"
        }
    ],
[
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811aefcb7880316e4497406"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 1",
            "company_location": "Texas, United States"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811afb7b7880316e4497407"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 2",
            "company_location": "South Carolina, United States"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5811afbfb7880316e4497408"),
            "company_name": "TestCompanyName 3",
            "company_location": "Florida, United States"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Not sure what you did there, but I need to update (by object ID) a single record / array inside the career_development field which contains multiple arrays. Can you give me an example?